# Adding authorization bearer token to ASP.NET web form page header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm writing an ASP.NET 4.6.1 web forms application with Web Api 2.2 and ASP.NET Identity 2. The application originally used forms authentication but we decided to add a mobile device application so web forms authentication wouldn't work.

I decided to authenticate with bearer tokens instead. I'm able to send my username and password to the authentication endpoint at `localhost:35000/token` and receive a bearer token. I also had to change the class `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` from within the `Page` classes in my application. From there I am able to authenticate and interact with my application just as before when I send the requests through Postman.

How do I get my application to automatically include the bearer token for all requests? My guess would be to extend the Application class and add the headers on every `Begin_Request`. Does anyone have any code that would accomplish this with ASP.NET Web Forms?